# 100% loss of my website content. I couldn't find cached pages on the net. Need help, please!

Tags: cache, personal-website

I had a website that I actively used from about 2/2014 through 10/2014. The site is www.tatumparnell.com. It was a collection of personal stories which mean the world to me, but the site is now down and the website builder can't recover it due to the time lapsed (over 30 days). 
I had it backed up to a computer, not the cloud, and that computer is no longer in my possession. My fault, no lecture necessary. 
I'm a novice in this area and I'm hoping someone can help. I've contacted some of my followers to check the cached pages from their devices, but most have new devices since then and the others didn't find the content. And I can't find a simple way for iPad users to check for cached pages.
I want to start a site again but can't properly recreate the content.
Is there any hope?

Comment: Did you use a web host?? You can contact them for a backup. Otherwise, I am not sure what can be done.

Comment: What you mean by you lost content? Did you contact to hosting provider? Is your site hacked? have you checked site logs?

Comment: did you try the internet archive wayback machine? It might have copies of it.

Comment: @TatumParnell Users here won't know anything about your site (e.g., is it static or dynamic?), so could only suggest various things, like check your own browser's cache, and hard drive for deleted files, or the various archive sites on the Internet. See the duplicate question for other suggestions. Good luck.